# What to do if Start Import option is not visible in MySQL?

Tags: mysql-workbench

As you can see in the below picture, I'm not able to see the "Start Import" option. Can anyone help me with this? And if you see in the second picture where I have hidden my taskbar and I have pointed to  the button which I'm looking for. So how can I get that button on the main screen as we can't scroll in the "Data Import" window.

[image: I'm not able to see the "Start Import" option.]

[image: I have hidden my taskbar and I have pointed to the button which I'm looking for.]

Comment: Do you have admin rights on that DB?

Comment: yes I do. Actually its just a sample DB which I have to practice on. There is an import option down below but I'm not able to see it and the words are also blurry

Comment: It is quite annoying, they could have added a scroll. As a workaround you can choose the "Import Progress" or "Export Progress" tab at top and the Start button is visible from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have an exported file that has only data or both structure and data.

If your exported file only contains data, then check If you exported the database only contains data, then you have to create all the tables inside your new database.

In MySQL Workbench, we can easily export with both Structure and Data.

Comment: It's not regarding the Data nor the structure. I'm talking about the button that's there "Start Import" which is not visible for me.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem. sorted out by adjusting the display resolution and scale settings of screen. Also the first dialog worked for me.
below what worked for me
scale 125%
display resolution 1920 X 1080

Answer (score 0):

you can use the PowerShell to import the database instead of mysql workbench,
all you need to do is locate the mysql.exe file on your system, for me its on
`C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.26\bin`

so the command would be like this for importation  on windows:

```
C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.26\bin\mysql.exe -u [db_user] -p[password] -h 127.0.0.1 [db_name] < backup-file.sql
```

on Linux:

```
mysql -u [db_user] -p[password] -h 127.0.0.1 [db_name] < backup-file.sql
```